# Given undirected weighted connected graph, s,t. Find path from s to t that its most weighted edge is low as possible

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Given: undirected weighted connected graph. s,t are vertices.

Question: Find an algorithm as efficient as possible that returns a path from s to t. In that path, the edge that has the highest weight, will has the least weight as possible. So if we have 5 paths from s,t and for every path we have the heaviest edge, so the minimum edge of these 5.

What I've tried:

1. Use **some algorithm** to find the shortest path between s and t.
2. Delete all the edges that are not part of the shortest paths we've found
3. Use BFS with some modification, We run BFS depending on the number of paths from s to t. Every time we find a maximum edge and store it in an array, then we find the minimum of the array.

I'm struggling to find an algorithm that can be ran in (1), Bellman ford won't work - because it has to be directed graph. Dijkstra won't work because we don't know if it has negative circles or negative edges. And Prim is for finding MST which I'm not aware of how it can help us in finding the shortest path.  Any ideas?

And other from that, If you have an algorithm in mind that can solve this question, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm).  Add edges as usual and stop as soon as s and t are in the same cluster.

The idea is that at each stage of the algorithm we have effectively added all edges below a certain weight threshold.  Therefore, if s and t are in the same cluster then there is a route between them consisting entirely of edges with weight less than the threshold.

Comment: Is it possible to use Prim's algorithm and then continue with 2) and 3) to find what minimum edge of the heaviest edges in the paths? I ask this because I don't understand how *just* using Prim's algorithm will yield the requested result..

Comment: If you use Kruskal, then the largest weight on the path will be equal to the last edge you used to connect points

Comment: How can you use Kruskal algorithm? The weights aren't necessarily *positive*.

Comment: I don't think the weights have to be positive, simply start with the smallest and continue as normal

Comment: Well, it will work if we multiply all the edges with a constanct *c* big enough so all the edges will become positive. But even then, We'll find a MST. Will we have many paths from s to t or just one path after running this algorithm? If just one path it is trivial, but what if we have many paths?

Comment: Each set in Kruskal is a tree, so there will be a single route from s to t

Comment: Yup. You're totally right. The time complexity is `ElogV` though. Do you think we can do better than that?

Comment: As recommended on the wiki page, using a good [disjoint set structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) reduces complexity to almost O(E).

Comment: Well Kruskal and Prim can yield different MSTs (Unless all the weights are unique - which isn't defined in the question), meaning there may be more than one path from s to t. Meaning your algorithm of just using Kruskal will fail.

Comment: If there is more than one path with the same heaviest edge, which do you wish to have as a result?  If any will do, then it doesn't matter that there may be different paths.  If you want the shortest out of these, then just run Dijkstra on the subgraph consisting of all edges less than the weight threshold found via Kruskal.

Comment: If there's more than one path from s to t, it doesn't mean there will be two (or any) identical heaviest edges.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by converting into a MST problem, basically the path from s to t in the MST would be the path which has the least possible maximum weight

Comment: Who said I will get just one path?

Comment: In a tree every vertex will have a unique path from source to destination, did  you want all such paths ?

Answer (score 0):

1. find the most negative edge in the graph
2. add that (weight+1) to every edge.
3. Now all edge are positive so you can apply Dijkstra's algorithm
4. you can get the shortest_path between source and destination
5. Now count the number of edges between source and destination (say x)
6. Real shortest path will be: shortest_path - x * (weight+1)